# iptables and password protection

Tags: passwords, iptables

I am trying to find the way to block all web-pages that I browse that use plaintext password  for their logins with iptables.

Here is the command I tried, something it wrong with it. How do I enter this command? This is for educational purpose only. Say, if I use "password" for all my logins.

Thanks.

nata@nata-VirtualBox:~$ **iptables -A OUTPUT -s match --string "password" --dport 80 -p tcp -j DROP**
iptables v1.4.12: unknown option "--string"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

nata@nata-VirtualBox:~$ **iptables -A OUTPUT -m string --string "password" --dport 80 -p tcp -j DROP**
string: Could not determine whether revision 1 is supported, assuming it is.
iptables v1.4.12: unknown option "--dport"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string password --algo bm -j DROP
```

To get help on a specific match, you can do:

```
iptables -m Match-Name --help
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it!

The question is how can I test it? 

All the pages I knew with http are no longer using http. Does anyone know any http login pages?

Comment: Just append the password to a URL and check. For example, http://www.somesite.com/?password

Comment: I got a couple of different errors. Are they "good error" in this case?

Comment: Here are the errors
XML Parsing Error: unexpected parser state Location: jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja!/chrome/toolkit/content/global/netError.xhtml Line Number 311, Column 58: <div id="ed_netInterrupt">&netInterrupt.longDesc;</div> ---------------------------------------------------------^
Other error
Request Timeout
The server timed out while waiting for the browser's request. 
Reference #2.7ba402cc.1391541578.0

Comment: Yes, that looks good. Basically the page timed out. "The server timed out while waiting for the browser's request." Basically the TCP connect happened, but the request never reached the server because the one packet containing the password was dropped. You can do iptables -nL -v to see the packet counters increase for your rule (it it matches). If your intent is not the timeout, then you do apply the REJECT target (replace DROP with REJECT).